# travis-ci job with bintray dependencies

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

My [travis build job](https://travis-ci.org/t1/deployer/jobs/150568840) constantly fails, because it can't resolve the dependencies I have on artifacts from bintray.

It simply says: `Failed to execute goal on project deployer: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.github.t1:deployer:war:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.github.t1:test-tools:jar:1.1.1`, even when I add bintray to my `repositories` in the pom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dependencies are all in [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter), add a file `.travis.settings.xml` containing:

`xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd'
          xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>bintray</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>bintray</name>
                    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>bintray</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>`

And add the following line to your `.travis.yml`:

`install: mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true --batch-mode --show-version --settings .travis.settings.xml`

If you also need plugins or dependencies from other repositories, add them just as you did in your local `settings.xml`.